# How can I validate multiple grouped inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this structure here:

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="1a">
    <input id="1b">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="2a">
    <input id="2b">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="3a">
    <input id="3b">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="4a">
    <input id="4b">
  </div>
</div>
```

If the user leaves everything empty, there is no problem. But when he enters for example something into `1a` and leaves `1b` empty, this should cause an error. So how can I find out if `a & b` is filled for each row? It's a bit tricky and I have no idea how to deal with this.

Comment: each row have two input? when input first, must input second?

Comment: Yes for example. If you fill out one input of a row, the second one must be filled out as well. It doesn't matter if it's the first or second one

Comment: Your example contains no JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: @StackSlave You noticed that well. As I mentioned, I don't know how to approach this problem, so yes, I do. I'm not stupid, but I'm not making much progress here.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this simple way

```js
$('button').on("click", () => {
  $('body').find(".row").each(function(index, row){
     var count = 0;
     $(row).find("input").each(function(i, input) {
        if($(input).val() !== "")
         count++;
     })
     if(count === 1)
      alert("Row " + (index + 1) + " is invalid");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="1a">
    <input id="1b">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="2a">
    <input id="2b">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="3a">
    <input id="3b">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="4a">
    <input id="4b">
  </div>
</div>

<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Mr. Jo

Comment: I'm currently checking it out if it fits my implementation because my example is very basic. I'll let you know but generally this is what I was looking for.

Comment: I'll do ASAP if everything works. Maybe I've a question or so :) If it's ok.

Comment: Yes, Let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: Is it ok? Basically, if the answer is suitable for the question which is described, it would be accepted to help other people that you've found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
const  inRow  = document.querySelectorAll('.row')
  ,    valida = document.querySelector('button')
  ,    respon = document.querySelector('output')
  ;
valida.onclick =_=>
  {
  let OK = true
  inRow.forEach(eR=>
    {
    let vals = 0
    eR.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(eI=>{ vals+=eI.value.length ? 1:0 })
    if (vals===1) OK=false
    })
  respon.value = OK ? 'OK' : 'bad'
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row"> <input id="1a"> <input id="1b"> </div>
  <div class="row"> <input id="2a"> <input id="2b"> </div>
  <div class="row"> <input id="3a"> <input id="3b"> </div>
  <div class="row"> <input id="4a"> <input id="4b"> </div>
</div>

<button>validate</button> <output></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally multiple [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Forms) (ex `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc) should be inside a [`<form>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). Moreover, the behavior described is called [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) which requires said `<form>` tag to be triggered by a [`"submit"` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event).

- The following demo features proper HTML

  - `<form>` and `<fieldset>` instead of `<div>`
  - added `<output>` for each `<fieldset>`
- Also the JavaScript is designed to show a message when any pair of `<input>` has a `.value` and the other doesn't.

  - The message: `<output>Complete data input</output>`
- This pseudo-form validation is triggered whenever a user enters data within an `<input>` and then clicks (aka `"blur"` event). This entire chain of actions combined is the `"change"` event.
- The `<form>` tag is registered to the `"change"` event so if any of the `<input>` within the `<form>` is the event origin (aka `event.target` - the `<input>` that the user triggers a `"change"` event on).

```js
const form = document.forms[0];

form.onchange = reqData;

function reqData(event) {
  let origin = event.target;
  if (origin.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    const parent = origin.parentElement;
    const output = parent.querySelector('output');
    const inputs = [...parent.querySelectorAll('input')];
    let total = inputs.length;
    let count = 0;
    for (let input of inputs) {
      if (input.value) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count < total && count > 0) {
      output.style.opacity = '1';
    } else {
      output.style.opacity = '0';
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
output {
  opacity: 0;
  color: tomato
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input><br>
    <input> <output>Complete data input</output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input><br>
    <input> <output>Complete data input</output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input><br>
    <input> <output>Complete data input</output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input><br>
    <input> <output>Complete data input</output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```